# Can I use method="post" in a html input?

Tags: html

Can I use method="post" in a html input?  Or does it have to be in a form?

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="inputstuff" method="post">
</div>
```

Comment: For reference, see the list of [available attributes for `<input>` elements on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes).

Answer (score 3):

You can only do that in a form